# Java - Force compile a .java file

Tags: java

Alright, I'm not very knowledgeable in Java, and I don't even know if this is possible, but here I go anyway.
I have taken a .class file from a JAR and decompiled it. I have edited it to what I want, but now I want to recompile it. Is it possible to recompile that one .java file so I can then place it back inside the jar file? When I try to recompile it by setting the source path it says there is an error inside one of the .java files that my file references (is that the word for it?) even though there is not.

EDIT: The decompile WAS successful.
Errors when recompiling:

> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftServer.java:619: error: not a statement
> ex;
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftServer.java:629: error: not a statement
> ex;
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftServer.java:637: error: not a statement
> ex;
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftServer.java:646: error: not a statement
> exception;
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:194: error: illegal start of expression
> static class _cls1
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: malformed floating point literal
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:215: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit.event._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.event.block.Action[action.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\event\CraftEventFactory.java:216: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> {
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:63: error: illegal start of expression
> static class _cls1
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: malformed floating point literal
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:104: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(net.minecraft.server._cls1..SwitchMap.net.minecraft.server.Entity.EntitySize[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\net\minecraft\server\Entity.java:105: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> {
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:55: error: illegal start of expression
> static class _cls1
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: malformed floating point literal
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:161: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.block._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\block\BlockFace.java:162: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> {
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:483: error: illegal start of expression
> static class _cls1
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: malformed floating point literal
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:572: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.TreeType[type.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:573: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> {
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: malformed floating point literal
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^
> C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftWorld.java:1244: error: case, default, or '}' expected
> switch(org.bukkit.craftbukkit._cls1..SwitchMap.org.bukkit.block.BlockFace[face.ordinal()])
> ^

Comment: Did you [decompile](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/java_decompiler/java_decompiler.php) it successfully?

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: Try recompiling it *without* editing it first.

Comment: Lion: The decompile was successful. Synesso: Added. Keith: I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this practice you need to make sure of a two things:

1. Is the new source valid after you decompile and modify it?
2. Does the source rely on any other classes? If so, they must be in the classpath for `javac`

With some rare exceptions (depending upon what you are trying to hack), this should be enough.

EDIT

It seems the source is not valid. Take your first error message, for example:

```
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\DECOMP~1\src\org\bukkit\craftbukkit\CraftServer.java:619: error: not a statement ex; ^
```

There is something that is not a statement in `CraftServer.java` line 619.

PS, taking a look at bukkit.org, it seems that this software is open source. Do you really need to decompile it?

Comment: The new source is valid, yes. The source does rely on other classes, and I have set the classpath to a folder containing the .class files. (Should I set it to the JAR? Sorry, I'm very new to Java)

Comment: Yes, the one I'm using is an unofficial fork of it, and I would like to change a few things. Anyhow, I think it't the decompiler that is screwing up the code, however I'm not really sure. I'm just going to close this. Thanks so much for the help anyway. (P.S. Line 619 was "ex;" and the line above it "IOException ex;". Just don't think something is right.)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have remove all the syntax errors then try to set the class path of that jar file then compile your file as it may be using the class references that are present in that class file.